# sql server if block errors when running a stored proc inside - gives a syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have a script for deployment which is **rerunable**. So I check if the table is there before renaming it.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  * FROM    sys.objects  WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Schema]')  AND type IN ( N'U' ) )  
BEGIN
sp_rename [Schema], [SchemaInfo] 
END
```

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near 'sp_rename'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'Schema', N'SchemaInfo';
```

IMHO you should never call a stored procedure without `EXEC`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with EXEC statement in followng way:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  * FROM    sys.objects  WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Schema]')  AND type IN ( N'U' ) )  
BEGIN
EXEC sp_rename [Schema], [SchemaInfo] 
END
```