# sp_rename programming error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can you please advise on how to write this code properly:

```
declare @str nvarchar(50)
Set @str = '[table1].[column_name1]'
sp_RENAME @str, 'column2', 'COLUMN'
```

It currently gives an error

> *Incorrect syntax near 'sp_RENAME'*

This should be equivalent with:

```
sp_RENAME '[table1].[column1]', '[column2]', COLUMN
```

that is used to rename a column from a table.

I need to use the first method because this happens as a general step in a procedure.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always use `EXEC` when calling stored procedures. The lazier syntax you're using is eligible for the first statement in the batch, but not later.

Comment: Hi Aaron, it's good to know that; not sure what you refer to exactly by lazy syntax?

Comment: Typing `sp_something` is definitely lazier than `EXEC sp_something`, no?

Comment: Oh, I see now, thanks for explaining. In my case it was just not knowing the right syntax.

Comment: Keep in mind that comments here are not always just for you - they are often for other (future) readers as well. And this is very common lazy syntax ([this issue comes up a lot - here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568275/sql-server-if-block-errors-when-running-a-stored-proc-inside-gives-a-syntax-er)), even if in your specific case it wasn't explicitly lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried your code and had no problems at all, could it be that you forgot to use "execute" to call the stored procedure?

```
declare @str nvarchar(50)
Set @str = '[table1].[column_name1]'
execute sp_RENAME @str, 'column2', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Thank you tr3! Indeed I had forgotten to use the execute keyword.